# Передача значений из родительского компонента в дочерний во Vue

Tags: vue.js

Коллеги, я новичок во vue, подскажите пожалуйста, такая проблема.

Использую стек laravel + vue.

У меня есть два компонента. Первый - таблица, второй - форма добавления нового элемента (модальное окно бутстрапа, обернутое в компонент vue).

На форме есть список множественного выбора. Я через `props` передаю все `options` для списка из родительского компонента (таблицы) и хочу, чтоб, когда я открою форму, все элементы списка были выбраны.

Делаю все по документации. Чтоб не менять из дочернего компонента значения родительского, я создаю локальное значение в дочернем компоненте через `data`. Но в момент использования это локальное значение всегда пустое!

1. Вызов дочернего компонента (формы добавления):

   ```
       <table class="table">
           <thead>
           <tr>
               <th scope="col">#</th>
               <th scope="col">id приложения</th>
               <th scope="col">Наименование</th>
               <th scope="col">Описание</th>
               <th scope="col">Картинка</th>
               <th scope="col">URL</th>
               <th scope="col"></th>
           </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
           <tr v-for="sportSite in sportSites">
               <th scope="row">{{ sportSite.id }}</th>
               <td>
                   <template v-for="application in sportSite.applications">
                      id {{ application.id }} => {{ application.name }} <br>
                   </template>

               </td>
               <td>{{ sportSite.name }}</td>
               <td>{{ sportSite.description }}</td>
               <td>
                   <img style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" :src="sportSite.image" >
               </td>
               <td>
                   <a :href="sportSite.url" target="_blank">{{ sportSite.url }}</a>
               </td>
               <td>
               </td>
           </tr>

           </tbody>
       </table>

     </div>
   </template>

   <script>
     import { EventBus } from '../../app';

     export default {
       name: "SportSitesTable",
       created() {
       },
       mounted(){
           this.loadTable();
           this.getApplications();
       },
       methods:{
           loadTable: function () {
               window.axios.get('/sport_sites_all')
                   .then(resp => {
                       this.sportSites = resp.data.data;
                   }).catch(err => {
                       console.error("Ошибка загрузки данных с сервера!");
                       console.error(err);
               });
           },
           getApplications: function () {
                window.axios.get('/applications/all')
                   .then(resp => {
                       this.applicationsAll = resp.data.applications.data;
                       this.$forceUpdate();
                   }).catch(err => {
                    console.error('Ошибка получения списка приложений!');
                    console.error(err);
                });
           }
       },
       data(){
           return {
               sportSites: [],
               applicationsAll: [],
           }
       },
     }
   </script>
   ```
2. Реализация дочернего компонента (где множественный селект):

   ```
   <template>
     <div>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary my-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sportSiteAdd">
           Добавить
       </button>

       <div class="modal fade" id="sportSiteAdd" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="sportSiteAddLabel" aria-hidden="true">
           <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
               <div class="modal-content">
                   <div class="modal-header">
                       <h5 class="modal-title" id="sportSiteAddLabel">Добавить спортивный сайт</h5>
                       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                       </button>
                   </div>
                   <div class="modal-body">

                       <ul class="alert-danger">
                           <li v-for="error in errors">
                               {{ error[0] }}
                           </li>
                       </ul>

                       <form>
                           <div class="form-group">
                               <label for="name">Заголовок</label>
                               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" v-model="formFields.name">
                           </div>

                           <div class="form-group">
                               <label for="image">Картинка</label>
                               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="image" name="image" v-model="formFields.image">
                           </div>

                           <div class="form-group">
                               <label for="url">URL</label>
                               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="url" name="url" v-model="formFields.url">
                           </div>

                           <div class="form-group">
                               <label for="description">Описание</label>
                               <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description" v-model="formFields.description"></textarea>
                           </div>

                           <div>
                               <label class="typo__label">Связанные приложения</label>
                               <multiselect v-model="applications"
                                            tag-placeholder="Связанные приложения"
                                            placeholder="Поиск"
                                            label="name"
                                            track-by="id"
                                            :options="allApplications"
                                            :multiple="true"
                                            :taggable="true">
                               </multiselect>
                           </div>

                       </form>

                   </div>
                   <div class="modal-footer">
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="submit">Сохранить</button>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
         </div>
     </div>
   </template>

   <script>
     import { EventBus } from '../../app';
     import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'

     export default {
       name: "SportSitesAdd",
       props: ['allApplications'],
       mounted: function(){
       },
       methods:{
           submit: function (e) {
               window.axios.post('/sport_site/add/', this.formFields)
                   .then(res => {
                       console.log('Saved!');
                       $('#sportSiteAdd').modal('hide');

                       this.formFields.name = '';
                       this.formFields.image = '';
                       this.formFields.url = '';
                       this.formFields.description = '';

                       EventBus.$emit('reloadApplicationsTable');
                   }).catch(err => {
                   if(err.response.status === 422){
                       this.errors = err.response.data.errors || [];
                   }
                   console.error('Ошибка сохранения!');
               });
           },
       },
       data(){
           return {
               formFields: {
                   name: '',
                   image: '',
                   url: '',
                   description: '',
               },
               applications: this.allApplications,
               errors: [],
           }
       },
       components: {
           Multiselect
       },
     }

   </script>
   ```

При этом, если я укажу в качестве `options` и `values` в списке свойство `allApplications` то все работает.

Но сами понимаете, это никуда не годится.

Во-первых, vue предупреждает, что я из дочернего меняю значение в родительском, во вторых, при удалении элемента из списка, он удаляется из родительского. И список так потихоньку "пустеет"))

Если удалить все, то и выбирать будет нечего потом, так как элементов не останется в родительском компоненте.

Вот результат, который я бы хотел видеть, то есть, открываешь - и все выбрано:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

В JS объекты передаются по ссылке. Это значит что когда Вы пишите `applications: this.allApplications` - вы не создаете новый объект, а передаете ссылку на исходный. Поэтому все действия как с исходным, так и с "новым" объектом, отображаются друг на друге.

В строке `applications: this.allApplications` напишите так `applications: Object.assign({}, this.allApplications)` - это должно решить проблему

П.С: либо так

```
computed: {
  applications() {
  return Object.assign({}, this.allApplications)
  }
}
```

Comment: Не помогло. У меня скопировался туда пустой объект. Вывел что там при маунте компонента. Вот http://joxi.ru/YmExjOMT0PJz7r

Comment: сделайте это в методе computed

Answer (score 1):

Есть один простой способ, нужно создать вотчер на allApplications

```
watch: {
  allApplications: {
    immediate: true,
    handler(value) {
      this.applications = { ...value };
    },
  }
}
```